# The patent claim one benefit of purification and then try to over reach. Nothing new

Tags: patentability, obviousness, us20140093916

In reference to the patent: [US20140093916](https://www.google.com/patents/US20140093916)

What is new about it? it is just the same as other protein based affinity purification.